# How can I find the stored energy in a 2d triangle that has a different electric potential at each point?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am writing a FEM solver for a project. I need to calculate the total energy stored in my mesh so that I can compute the capacitance of the solution.

So obviously I have to loop through all the elements and work out the stored energy in every element.

So if I have an element that consists out of three points in 2D, let's say:
X = [0 ; 1 ; 2] meters
Y = [0 ; 1 ; 0] meters
E = [0 ; 2 ; 1] volts (Potential at the point)

What would be the stored energy in that element? (assume 1m depth)

How would I work it out?

Thank you for your time guys!

EDIT: In reply to you guys. The equation for energy in an electric field is:

Energy = 0.5 * volume integral of ( D.E )

My case is 2d, so obviously that is the area integral. E and D are dependent on their X and Y position ( I have all these values already). I just don't know how to go from this triangle and electric potential, to stored energy. My integration is a bit sucky.

Comment: There is no stored energy in this case, because there is no charge present. Electrical potential is only the *potential* to transfer energy when a charge is introduced.

Comment: @ThePhoton I think the intended meaning is capacitance of the structure, the solution method is causing a mismatch in vocabulary. Sadly, it has been 4 years since I did any FEM and I remember thinking at the time I would remember it...

Comment: If the solution gives both charge and potential at each point, you probably just multiply one by the other to get energy, then sum up over all the mesh points. Maybe you get charge density instead of charge, then you need to also multiply by volume at each element.

Comment: @ThePhoton He is probably calculating charge with a set test voltage. This is what I remember, and then you use that to calculate your voltage with some fancy equation :)